# What is name of the anime that takes a group of kids going on a weird train that will accidentally take them into another dimension?

Tags: story-identification, anime

So I saw this anime as a kid, a group of kids go into a really weird train that can talk. It takes them to a different dimension. Turns out they some weird thing that can make them transform. But it the end it’s just a dream of the main character. The protagonist and the other kids gets stuck in the elevator and they go unconscious. That’s the finale.

I know it’s not a lot but I can’t get it out of my head. I remember that it used to play in Jetx or CN or DisneyXD.

Comment: Was this a Japanese anime or a cartoon series?

Comment: When did you see this (in terms of year, since we don't know how old you are)? Was it new or a repeat of an older series? Can you think of answers to any of the prompts in [this FAQ page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) that might help people find the right series? Click [edit] and add as many details as you can.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds a bit like **Digimon Frontier** (2002).

It begins with a talking train taking the protagonists..

[image]
[image]

..and the kids can transform into Digimon..

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

..the last episode has an elevator.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks super-trippy

Comment: And I haven't even shown pictures of when the train is doing loopings. https://files.catbox.moe/6lnbs0.jpg, https://files.catbox.moe/kzoxbn.jpg, https://files.catbox.moe/prn7bj.jpg, https://files.catbox.moe/9ak7ip.jpg